# UILabel getting displayed differently on 3rd and 4th gen iPods

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uilabel

I have a UILabel which behaves differently on 3rd & 4th Gen iPods.

My UILabel is:

```
<UILabel: 0x881e80; frame = (10 76; 70 28); text = 'Produits Indisponibles'; clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x863fe0>>
```

Now, on 4th gen iPod it works fine and text wraps into 2 lines properly but on 3rd gen iPod text wraps but second word (Indisponibles) disappears. What could be the reason?

If I increase the frame width by 1 more pixel, it works fine. Here is my code:

```
self.titleLabel = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero] autorelease];
                self.titleLabel.text = @"Produits Indisponibles";
                self.titleLabel.isAccessibilityElement = NO;
                self.titleLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
                self.titleLabel.opaque = NO;
                self.titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
                self.titleLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
                self.titleLabel.numberOfLines = 2;
                self.titleLabel.highlightedTextColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
                self.titleLabel.baselineAdjustment = UIBaselineAdjustmentAlignBaselines;
                self.titleLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
                self.titleLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:11];
                CGSize aLabelSize = CGSizeMake(self.frame.size.width - 20, 28);
                CGSize aStringSize = [self.titleLabel.text sizeWithFont:self.titleLabel.font constrainedToSize:aLabelSize lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
                CGFloat theYOrigin = self.bounds.size.height - 34;

                if (aStringSize.height < 15) {
                    theYOrigin = theYOrigin + 14;
                }
                self.titleLabel.frame = CGRectMake(10, theYOrigin, aLabelSize.width, aStringSize.height);
                [self addSubview:self.titleLabel];
```

Comment: Seems logical that your label may not be wide enough to display the entire word.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Retina displays use Helvetica Neue as the system font, while older models use normal Helvetica.  It's probably related to the different font metrics.  Hard-code a font you know is available on both to see if they display consistently.

Answer (score 0):

I do not see the reason but when I increased the width of the frame by 2 more pixels it worked. Anyone know the reason for this will be enlightening.